# Setting Subreport Name on Action

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way that I can dynamically set the name property of a subreport based on the action of a table cell?  For example, when I run the report interactively and click the 'TEST1' text, it would load subreport 'TEST' in the subreport (in the bordered area)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, a subreport can only be set at design and cannot be altered.

You can however drill down to reports by setting action options on an object such as a textbox or placeholder (right-click Properties...)

[image]